# 2007 Dodge Charger 2.7L A/T - Limp Mode on Heavy Throttle & Hanging in Gear

Tags: engine, transmission, dodge, repair, chrysler

Trying to help out my neighbor here.

2007 Charger with a 2.7L. 100k+ Miles on the body/transmission.

"If I drive very carefully I can get it up to highway speed. If I romp on it, or push it too hard to pass etc, seems to go into limp mode. Sometimes the speedo will follow the tach. Like it's hanging in gears."

How should we start troubleshooting?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Does anyone know if the "Key Dance" will display transmission codes? It appears to show Power-train codes, which I assume would cover the transmission codes, but are there Chrysler specific codes that do not present themselves in the DTC P-Codes, requiring different tools/protocols to read?

I am not sure I can read transmission codes with my BAFX and TorquePro?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have they had the codes read? I'm assuming the check engine light has come on since it's going into limp mode. Getting those would be a great first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: Does the key-dance display transmission codes?

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "key-dance display", but if you're talking about the scroll on the dash while the vehicle is started/running, then no, not usually. An OBDII reader should pick up the diagnostic codes which are present.

Comment: http://www.300cforums.com/forums/general-discussion/158114-checking-codes-doing-key-dance.html

This is what I was referring to. 

Does anyone know if the "Key Dance" will display transmission codes?

I am not sure I can read transmission codes with my BAFX and TorquePro?

Comment: You should be able to pull the codes either way. Your BAFX is an ELM327 bluetooth interface, which will read any stored engine or transmission codes. TorquePro may be a little easier way to read the codes than trying to catch them all on the display. I'm not sure how generic the codes are going to be as listed on the display. TorquePro will give you a little more information, I'd bet.

Comment: If the MIL is on with a p0500/1 or similar look for codes and communication with the EBCM. If the TCM doesn’t see wheel speed from the EBCM it can cause a no shift or tach/speedo inop condition. Also i doubt you’d be able to read anything other than a p0700/50x or a u-code for implausible data on the PCM side.

Comment: In case anyone is having this issue... We replaced the Camshaft Position Sensor with a new Mopar CMPS, and the issue was resolved